# Save canvas image on local mobile storage for IOS/Android

Tags: javascript, cordova, canvas, fabricjs, phonegap-build

Im using the fabric javascript library to create a custom image. All the data is saved in a canvas and is shown using canvas tag. After displaying the image, I would like to give the user the option to save it locally. Anyone has any idea how to do that? The solution should work for IOs and Android, I've tried several alternatives but still no luck.

[Update 1]
I tried using the Canvas2ImagePlugin but for some reason my app restarts when running the window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary command.

My code (I want to save the image when the users touches the saveButton):

```
$(document).on('click', '#saveButton', function(e){

    window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
    function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    },
    function(err){
        console.log(err);
    },
    document.getElementById('c')
);
```

});

This is shown in the browser logs after the app restarts:

deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. (13:09:28:529)
  at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1169
Channel not fired: onPluginsReady (13:09:28:542)
  at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1162
Channel not fired: onCordovaReady (13:09:28:550)
  at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1162
Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded (13:09:28:557)
  at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1162

I also noticed that when Netbeans builds my app, for some reason it deletes the plugin. This is part of the build output:

update-plugins:

cordova.cmd plugins 
cordova.cmd -d plugin remove org.devgeeks.Canvas2ImagePlugin

Calling plugman.uninstall on plugin "org.devgeeks.Canvas2ImagePlugin" for platform "android"
Uninstalling org.devgeeks.Canvas2ImagePlugin from android

[Update 2]

After some research I found out that I had to add the plugin manually in the file \nbproject\plugin.properties. Now its working perfectly. Thank you AtanuCSE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this plugin

[Canvas2ImagePlugin](https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin)

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="165px" height="145px"></canvas>
function onDeviceReady()
{
    window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
        function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
        },
        function(err){
            console.log(err);
        },
        document.getElementById('myCanvas')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Canvas2ImagePlugin now u can choose either to `save as jpg/png`, `set quality` and `set outputfolder`

```
function onDeviceReady()
{
    window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
        function(msg){
            console.log(msg);  //msg is the filename path (for android and iOS)
        },
        function(err){
            console.log(err);
        },
        document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
        '.jpg', // save as jpg
        80, // image quality
        'cunvaspluginfolder' //folder name
    );
}
```

Credit to [wbt11a](https://github.com/wbt11a) because make this plugin more configurable from original author.

Please download the new plugin here [Github source](https://github.com/wbt11a/Canvas2ImagePlugin)